# swift multiple userDefaults objects

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsuserdefaults

I am using this struct to save a token in my app:

```
struct LocalStore {

    static let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    static func saveToken(token: String) {
        userDefaults.setObject(token, forKey: "tokenKey")
    }

    static func getToken() -> String? {
        return userDefaults.stringForKey("tokenKey")
    }

    static func deleteToken() {
        userDefaults.removeObjectForKey("tokenKey")
    }

}
```

I know that I wan overwrite existing saved object but can I save multiple objects? Like this:

```
static func saveToken(token: String) {
        userDefaults.setObject(token, forKey: "tokenKey")
    }

static func saveFirstName(firstName: String) {
        userDefaults.setObject(firstName, forKey: "lastNameVal")
    }

static func saveLastName(lastName: String) {
        userDefaults.setObject(lastName, forKey: "firstNameVal")
    }
```

Comment: did you mean static func saveFirstName(firstName: String) {
        userDefaults.setObject(firstName, forKey: "lastNameVal")
    }

static func saveLastName(lastName: String) {
        userDefaults.setObject(lastName, forKey: "firstNameVal")
    }   I think you have a typo ?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Passing data from one end of the app to the other?

Comment: @EugeneZhenyaGordin Yes sry, I have edited my question now

Comment: @vikingosegundo I have edited my question. I wonder is its ok to create/save multiple objects/keys

Comment: and my question remains: why would you do that (hint: probably you are abusing NSUserDefaults)

Comment: @vikingosegundo when a user logs into my app I want to store the api_token / firstname / lastname. Those 3 values will be used all over the app later, so instead of making a API call each time I want to store it when logging in so that its ready to use later on

Comment: So what happened when you tried it? and in my opinion a token belongs into the keychain, other user information in a user model object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, as long as it has a different key. This is possible, however, from your example, you are saving your token object to multiple keys. There is nothing wrong with that if that is your intention.

User defaults is a form of persistent storage that can save many types of values (not just Strings).

Comment: I have edited my question since I typed the store functions wrong. What I wonder is if its OK to save multiple objects/keys like above?

Comment: yes, that's ok to store it like above as long as your key values are distinct, otherwise you'll be overwriting the values for the key

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer is right, but I want to show another way of how to deal with NSUserDefaults in Swift.

By using computed properties instead of methods or functions, it is easy to use NSUserDefaults as the backing variable — and as all set and get operations are performed through this property, no further code is needed to ensure that the property has the correct value.

From production code:

```
var sorting:DiscoverSortingOrder {
    set {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setInteger(newValue.rawValue, forKey: "DiscoverSorting")
        refresh() // will trigger reloading the UI
    }
    get {
        if let s = DiscoverSortingOrder(rawValue: NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().integerForKey("DiscoverSorting")){
            return s
        }
        return .New // Default value
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! To answer your last comment - Everything works fine now, the main reason I am using NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() instead of CoreData is that I only need to save 1 - 3 strings. I am still very new to swift so please correct me if its bad design to not use CoreData in my case

Comment: Model doesnt equal Core Data. If any user object would represent the same user, you could also use NSUserDefaults as backing store.